# Spring security and Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, security, tomcat

I'm facing a problem while trying to add j_spring_security_check as an action in my login.jsp

' method="POST">

This is my form, but when I type my default acc/pw admin/admin, instead of getting redirected to the users page, I get the following error

type Status report

message /java-blog/%3Cspring:url%20value=%22/j_spring_security_check%22%20/%3E

Can you give me a hand and tell me where the problem is?

I have security.xml where I've set login page as /login and intercept url as /users** and I've also imported the security.xml spring configuration bean into the applicationContext

The server I'm using is Tomcat 7.

Comment: what actual error are you getting

Comment: I haven't copied the form header properly:  <form class="form-signin" role="form" action='<spring:url value="/j_spring_security_check" />' method="POST"> - this is it, but there seems to be a problem with the "POST" method because when i submit my username and password, instead of getting redirected by the spring security to Users, i get the above error message /java-blog/%3Cspring:url%20value=%22/j_spring_security_check%22%20/%3E and it seems it can't be found, can the problem come from Tomcat, because the app was Tested on jetty and worked fine, or maybe it is in the encoding or controller.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to include the taglib at the top of your jsp file:

```
<%@ include file="../layout/taglib.jsp" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of

`<form class="form-signin" role="form" action='<spring:url value="/j_spring_security_check" />' method="POST">`

use this

`<form class="form-signin" role="form" action="<spring:url value='/j_spring_security_check' />" method="POST">`

Also make sure you have included the spring jsp taglibs in your login form jsp.